# using docker alpine for go produces "unknown revision" error during go get

Tags: docker, go, alpine-linux, dockerhub

I’ve the following docker which works ok, I was able to run it and build it successfully!

```
FROM golang:1.13.6 AS build-env



ENV GO111MODULE=on
ENV GOOS=linux
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0




RUN mkdir -p /go/src/github.company.corp/deng/fst-cl
WORKDIR /go/src/github.company.corp/deng/fsr-clie


COPY ./ ./

# build the code
RUN go build -v -o ./fsr  ./src/cmd/main.go
```

Now I want to change the image to use lighter docker image such as go alpine

So I change the from and added alpine version and also added git ,however the build is failing for
So go lib which doesn’t happen before the change, any idea what could be missing ?

```
FROM golang:1.13.6-alpine AS build-env



ENV GO111MODULE=on
ENV GOOS=linux
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0


## git is required to fetch go dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates git
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev


RUN mkdir -p /go/src/github.company.corp/deng/fst-cl
WORKDIR /go/src/github.company.corp/deng/fsr-clie


COPY ./ ./

# build the code
RUN go build -v -o ./fsr  ./src/cmd/main.go
```

The error is for specifid repo which resides on our company git repo, but I don’t understand why its happen on `golang:1.13.6-alpine` and works ok on `golang:1.13.6`  ????

Btw I try to use different version of go alpine without success…

**This is the error:**

```
get "github.company.corp/deng/logger-ut": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"github.company.corp/deng/logger-ut", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.company.corp/deng/logger-ut.git"} at //github.company.corp/deng/logger-ut?go-get=1
go: github.company.corp/deng/logger-ut@v1.0.0: reading github.company.corp/deng/logger-ut/go.mod at revision v1.0.0: unknown revision v1.0.0
```

Comment: *mostly*, Go doesn't interact with the C standard library, and isn't bothered by differences between Alpine and more conventional distros. That's only "mostly", though -- IIRC, it _does_ use the libc's stub resolver for DNS. I wonder if your company is using any interesting DNS protocol extensions. Obviously, that's not something we could investigate without a real, externally-accessible URL the issue reproduces with.

Comment: ...that said, do you have any compelling reason to use Alpine here? Except as noted above, Go's binaries don't use the system libc unless they're compiled with cgo extensions, so you might get some disk savings, but there'll be very little by way of memory savings; and, well, disk is cheap.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - thanks, AFAIK we dont have anything special , and im not sure how go alpine can be diffrent from the version which doesnt use it... the reason that we are trying to switch to alpine is that we have a lot of dockers images which need to load to k8s very quickly and it doesnt so we thinking on ways how to reduce them, like multi-stage , reduce layers if we can etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a lighter image and wish to use `apline`, you can use example below. Your final app image should be something like 7MB on `scratch`. Adjust it as it fits!

```
# STAGE 1: prepare
FROM golang:1.13.1-alpine3.10 as prepare

WORKDIR /source

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

RUN go mod download

# STAGE 2: build
FROM prepare AS build

COPY . .

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags "-s -w" -o bin/app -v your/app.go

# STAGE 3: run
FROM scratch as run

COPY --from=build /source/bin/app /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/app"]
```